# keycode shortcut each function

Tags: javascript, each, shortcut, keyevent, onkeydown

I'm working yet on a small script to capture keyevents and easily bind functions on them. But I'm stuck for now!

The problem is, that if I initalize more than one "eventhandler" it overides arguments from the first initialization.

Thousands of words do not say more than some lines of code. So, here's what I've done so far:

```
var keyCodes={a:65,b:66,c:67,d:68,e:69,f:70,g:71,h:72,i:73,j:74,k:75,l:76,m:77,n:78,o:79,p:80,q:81,r:82,s:83,t:84,u:85,v:86,w:87,x:88,y:89,z:90,"0":48,"1":49,"2":50,"3":51,"4":52,"5":53,"6":54,"7":55,"8":56,"9":57,f1:112,f2:113,f3:114,f4:115,f5:116,f6:117,f7:118,f8:119,f9:120,f10:121,f11:122,f12:123,shift:16,ctrl:17,control:17,alt:18,option:18,opt:18,cmd:224,command:224,fn:255,"function":255,backspace:8,"delete":8,enter:13,"return":13,left:37,up:38,right:39,down:40};

var keyCall = function(k, fn, c, e, k2, nk) {
    this.onkeydown = function() {
        nk = k.split(" ");
        c = e ? e.which : event.keyCode;
        if (nk.length > 1) {
            if (keyCodes[nk[0]] === c) {
                k2 = true;
            }
            if (keyCodes[nk[1]] === c && k2 === true) {
                fn();
                k2 = false;
            }
        } else if (keyCodes[nk[0]] === c) {
            fn();
        }
    };
};


keyCall('ctrl a', function() { // overridden by `keyCall('shift a'`
    alert('callback1');
});

keyCall('shift a', function() {
    alert('callback2');
});
```

I've optimized it for a highly minimum of bytes, if you think an annotated version is usefull, so just say it! For everyone who needs, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/HLUYt/)

**Update**

pascalfree has fixed it! But anoter problem is now coming up...

The "placeholder"-variable `k2` checks if the first key was/is pressed. But for now if you press and release `ctrl` and hit thereafter the `a`-key the function will fired. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the title is a bit confusing, I'm sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the onKeyPress event is bound to some html element like this:

`keyCall.apply( window.body, ['shift a', function() { alert('a') }] );`

In order to append additional events you can check if an eventhandler already is defined and call it in your new function:

```
var keyCall = function(k, fn, c, e, k2, nk) {
    var oldOnkeydown = this.onkeydown; //get old event handler
    this.onkeydown = function() {
        if( typeof oldOnkeydown == "function" ) { oldOnkeydown() } //call in new eventhandler.
        nk = k.split(" ");
        c = e ? e.which : event.keyCode;
        if (nk.length > 1) {
            if (keyCodes[nk[0]] === c) {
                k2 = true;
            }
            if (keyCodes[nk[1]] === c && k2 === true) {
                fn();
                k2 = false;
            }
        } else if (keyCodes[nk[0]] === c) {
            fn();
        }
    };
    //reset k2 onkeyup
    var oldOnkeyup = this.onkeyup;
    this.onkeyup = function() {
      if( typeof oldOnkeyup == "function" ) { oldOnkeyup() }
      k2 = false;
    };
};
```

I only added the 2 lines with comments. (+ onkeyup event at the end to solve problem from comments)

Source: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html

Comment: Such a dream! Shame on me, I've to accept! :) By the way, any ideas how to fix the problem with my "placeholder"-variable `k2`? I check with it if the first key was/is pressed. But for now if you press and release `ctrl` and hit thereafter the `a`-key the function will fired (not really useful).

Comment: Add an onkeyup event to this at the end of keyCall. (I updated my answer). Again it is necessary to call previous onkeyup events because there will be different 'instances' of k2.
@yckart